# Xamarin Mac - SIGSEGV

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, segmentation-fault, xamarin.mac

Sometimes I am getting an unknown SIGSEGV Error while executing my code.

The Stacktrace can be found [here](https://codepaste.net/j8ayso).
The Exception always occurs when expanding a View which is inside a StackView.

```
        NSAnimationContext.RunAnimation(ctx =>
        {
            ctx.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseOut);
            //((NSView)View.Animator).AlphaValue = !IsSmall ? 0 : 1;
            ((NSLayoutConstraint)heightConstraint.Animator).Constant = (IsSmall == true) ? SmallHeight : LargeHeight;
        }, null);
```

Also there is no difference if I don't expand the view with an animation.

I can't find out what is happening here, so hopefully someone can help me

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

Could it be that this happens because the Garbage Collector freed this view? I found out that the view is also not clickable and as said above, clicking the button will throw the SIGSEGV

Comment: `Also not expanding it with an animation does not affect the error.` ? Confused by your statement, do you mean if you do not use an `NSAnimationContext.RunAnimation` you still get the same error? As it appears to be faulting on the `sendAction:to:from:` (UI thread) Verify that your constraint value is valid.

Comment: How can I check the constraint? The expanding view is loaded multiple times into the stack view and some of them expand as expected, but some of them throw the said error. Also this does not occur always on the same one, it is completely random

Comment: Your link to the stack trace does not work - "You specified a snippet id or link that is invalid and cannot be displayed. Please using the Recent Snippets or My Snippets buttons to look up valid snippets."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The solution seems pretty easy. I was not storing the views in any variable which causes the Garbage Collector the collect these. Now I added a List which will be filled with the views and voila: It is working fine